# Redirect direct image urls requests and pass the original url value in the redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, post

Suppose I have someone (or Google Images) trying to access

`http://null.com/uploads/someimage.jpg` (actually any image in /uploads folder)

I'd want htaccess to redirect the user to

```
http://null.com/page/
```

HOWEVER, I need to pass the original url (`http://null.com/uploads/someimage.jpg`) to the redirection target page as a POST string value which the target php page can use to do stuff with it

Would it be possible to achieve that with htaccess?

UPDATE - and also, it would be interesting to have this working only when the user agent is a human operated browser, not a bot such as google bot, in this way Google and other search engines can crawl images appropriately without the redirection

Comment: Why this step: `http://null.com/page/?image=someimage.jpg`, why not passing it directly to the script?

Comment: oh I wasn't sure about that, is there a quick way to pass the original redirected URL value to the php page I want to redirect to? I need to store that into a value and then let the php page do something with it

Comment: Any parameter has to exist in the incoming URL and the second step can't add more parameters except when it is redirected to a script which in turn generates a second URL, to be, again, redirected to another script. In this case `page` is `uploads` and `someimage.jpg` is the image, so, yes, both parameters could be passed directly to the page script. For example: `page_script.php?page=uploads&image=someimage.jpg`

Comment: no I need to pass this url 'http://null.com/uploads/someimage.jpg' as it is to a page which will take that url as a string and do something with it; alternatively I could use 'someimage.jpg' but in the meanwhile I figured out what I really need in the end is the whole original URL... how to tell in htaccess "if the url points to an image in uploads, redirect the user to this page and pass the former original url as a post value? (i've edited my question a bit)

Comment: I think that's exactly what I am suggesting in my previous comment. You may want to update your question accordingly, though.

Comment: ok thanks I just did; but I haven't solved my problem yet - how to pass the original url value to the redirection target page?

Comment: Is `page` in  `redirect the user to this page and pass the former original url as a post value` a script?

Comment: yes php, I need to store the original url in a variable like $url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page\.php           [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .  page.php?url=uploads/%1 [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://null.com/uploads/someimage.jpg` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://null.com/page.php?url=uploads/someimage.jpg`

The string `uploads` is assumed to be fixed, while `someimage.jpg` can be any name.

The script name `page.php` is an example an can be any name also. Replace all instances in the rule-set.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

This answer is according to this description in OP comments:

> "...redirect the user to this page and pass the former original url as a post value..."

where `page` is a script.

NOTE: The parameters passed in the substitution URL can be captured with PHP using `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`, not `$_POST`.

#### UPDATE

Here is another version:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page\.php        [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg   page.php?url=$1.jpg [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://null.com/any/number/of/folders/someimage.jpg`

To:

`http://null.com/page.php?url=any/number/of/folders/someimage.jpg`

The rewrite rule is applied only when the incoming URL holds a file with extension `jpg` at the end of the path.

Comment: this almost works, thanks
I only have a problem with the last line in htaccess; because actually the content in /uploads could be in subfolders, not in the uploads root, how to include possible subfolders?

Comment: So it could be in any folder, like `http://null.com/folder/folder1/folder2/someimage.jpg`? If so, I will update my answer. Please confirm.

Comment: yes thank you I'm looking into it as well, will link my specific case once I'm done

Comment: I updated my answer, anyway. Hope it is what you need. If it isn't, just let me know.

Comment: thanks, it was very useful, I need to tweak it for wordpress but I think I can get there